# How to add translation into Microsoft translator hub CTF in multiple sentences?

Tags: c#, microsoft-translator

I already succeed building a translator machine which is able to translate and collecting the translation log using `translatemethod.cs` and `addtranslationmethod.cs` from https://github.com/MicrosoftTranslator/HTTP-Code-Samples/tree/master/CSharp.

However, the add translation only works if the input only 1 sentence. If I put more than 1 sentence, it can be translated, but it will not store in translator hub (CTF).

My question is if I want to add all the sentences input into translator HUB(CTF), do I need to turn my code using the `AddTranslationArrayMethod.cs` only or I need also change the translate method using `TranslateArrayMethod.cs`?

Is there anybody experienced about this? Can someone give me an idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Add Translations for multiple sentences into CTF using the AddTranslationArray method.

The TranslateArray method is available to request for the translations for multiple sentences. You will not need to use this for CTF. You can use this method for requesting the actual translations.